# Smallest enclosing circle proof

Tags: computational-geometry

Can someone explain to me the proof of Lemma 1 (iii) in this paper http://www.stsci.edu/~RAB/Backup%20Oct%2022%202011/f_3_CalculationForWFIRSTML/Bob1.pdf

I'm having trouble understanding the reasoning behind the infinitesimal perturbation.

Comment: I strongly advise you to have a look instead at the marvelous book "Computational Geometry" authors De Berg Van Kreveld, Overmars Schwarzkopf p. 86 paragraph "Smallest enclosing disks" 2nd Edition: they explain (a version of) this algorithm.

Comment: I have been reading that book, and indeed it is very good. They don't give an explanation for this fact though, which is how I came across the above paper, but I am unable to understand the proof.